# Flutter - Firebase - Google_Sign_In - The Supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-oauth

Attempting to register a new user using Google Auth throws the error "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Unable to parse Google id_token: "

Code successfully generates the idToken and accessToken.

Firebase Authentication works fine with Facebook and manual registration via email and password.

Can't figure out what is going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you need any more information just let me know.

```
  //sign in with google
  Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleAuth.accessToken, 
        accessToken: googleAuth.idToken
      );
      print(credential);

      final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      print('signed in' + user.displayName);


      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: OP, were you able to solve this? Having the same issue here.

Comment: Unfortunately no, every work around I developed would eventually break, returning with the same error. I added it to their buglist I think but nothing yet.

Comment: Hey how did you go about solving it? facing the same issue for only specific google account, the rest works.